# Hide a DropDownList in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, hide, html-select

I have a Simple query to ask..

I have a DropdownList,and it holds data which depends on values from DATABASE.

Now their can be 2 scenario:-

1)- DropdownList holds value(Not empty)
2)-DropdownList Doesnt hold values(Empty)

Now what I want is,I want to Hide the DropdownList and the LABEL(Select UserName) if it EMPTY..I hope am clear..!!

I tried This to hide DropDownList but it dint Work so How Can I hide both the Label and the DropDownList-

```
<label>
                    Select UserName :</label>
                @if (@ViewBag.UserName.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div id="uniform-undefined" class="selector" style="margin-right: 60px; margin-left: 10px;">
                        @Html.DropDownList("UserName", null, new { @visible= false })
                    </div>
                }
```

I tried this-I disabled my DropdownList when it gets empty and this code works..HOW?

```
@if (@ViewBag.UserName.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div id="uniform-undefined" class="selector" style="margin-right: 60px; margin-left: 10px;">
                        @Html.DropDownList("UserName", null, new { @disabled = true })
                    </div>
                }
```

Comment: @ViewBag.UserName is a list of username ?

Comment: Simply set your condition as greater than zero and inside it generate your dropdownlist

Comment: refer this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1658219.aspx

Comment: I have edited my code check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply adding "display: none" in the  tag like this:-

```
@if (@ViewBag.UserName.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div id="uniform-undefined" class="selector" style="margin-right: 60px; margin-left: 10px; display: none ;">
                        @Html.DropDownList("UserName", null, new { @disabled = true })
                    </div>
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following and it is working fine:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CLQty.Length, new SelectList(Model.Product.Length, length), new { @class = "form-control ",@disabled="disabled"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CLQty.Length, new SelectList(Model.Product.Length, length), new { @class = "form-control ", @style="display:none" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
@if (Model.Items.Count() > 0)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Selected, Model.Items);
    //Generate your dropdownlist here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (ViewBag.UserName !=null && (ViewBag.UserName as IList<string>).Count >0)
{
    <label>
    Select UserName :</label>
    <div id="uniform-undefined" class="selector" 
                                 style="margin-right: 60px; margin-left: 10px;">
           @Html.DropDownList() // do something here
    </div>
}
```

try this , and let me know i havent tried this

Answer (score 0):

You can add some jquery code to simply achieve your goal:

Your Viwe:

```
<div id="divUsers">
    <label>Select UserName :</label>        
    <div id="uniform-undefined" class="selector" 
                                  style="margin-right: 60px; margin-left: 10px;">
        @Html.DropDownList("UserName")
    </div>        
</div>
```

And then add this script to your view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (@ViewBag.UserName.Items.Count > 0)
        $("#divUsers").hide()
});
</script>
```